# Why is this jQuery load()-command repeated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gone through many stackoverflow posts and other websites to find a solution to this problem, but none of the solutions i could find either fit my problem or just straight up didn't work.

Im using javascript and jQuery (and some Java for background work) to build a page on a website. The page contains a table with data (the data is handled by Java) and i want to have that table refresh every 10 seconds. That works.

But now i also want to highlight all the cells that have changed values in them. For that, as you see in my code snippet, i just simply turn the background of those cells black. That works too.

My problem is that the color only changes for a split second before changing back to standard white. Using the console and playing around a bit i was able to find out that the table is actually reloaded twice, which to me must mean the load-command is executed twice.

```
window.setInterval(function () { 
 if (frozen == false) {
  $('table').load(document.URL + ' table');
  var elem = document.getElementById("freezebtn"); //This is a button generated by Java Code
  elem.style.background = getRandomColor();
  var tab = document.getElementsByTagName('table').item(1);
  var l = tab.rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i<l; i++) {
   var tr = tab.rows[i];
   var cll = tr.cells[1];
   var check = tr.cells[0];

 if(check.innerText === "getAsk") {
  var valAsk = cll.innerText;
  var ask = Number(valAsk);
 if (ask != loadPreviousAsk()) {
  console.log("TELEFONMAST!");
  cll.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
 }
}
//Do this for every other Updateable Cell
...

 }
cachePreviousValues(someValues,thatINeed,To,BeCached);
}
```

My Question is, what is/could be causing the repeat of the load command (or why won't the cells stay black at all)? 
Is there a better way of achieving what im trying to do?
Could my code sample be optimized in any other way?

Comment: That's because `$.fn.load()` is async, set logic inside complete callback: `$('table').load(document.URL + ' table', function(){/* your logic regarding loaded data here*/);`

Comment: I'm kinda new to js... what is "complete callback"?

Comment: I edited previous comment, but don't forget to check [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Thank you so much, i actually did this right before i gave up, but didn't reload to see if it worked ^^ Can you post this as answer so i can accept it tomorrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.fn.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is async (by default). To handle any logic regarding loaded data, you can use the complete callback:

```
$('table').load(document.URL + ' table', function(){/* your logic regarding loaded data here*/);
```